# Internal 19-USB 3.0 to normal USB-3.0a

Tags: usb, usb-3, chassis

I have the following problem. I have a new computer chassis, which has a front panel USB 3.0 with an internal connector, but my Asus M4GDP89 Pro/USB3 has only two back USB 3.0.

Is there a way to transform the internal connector to a USB3.0? I know that there are adapters for the other way around.
thanks
eactor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are also USB3.0 adapters available for converting two regular USB ports to an internal connector: [image: USB 3.0 adapter].

However I do not recommend something like this to you. That an USB 3.0 adapter exists does not necessarily means that it will work flawless in all situations. The more adapter and connections an USB3.0 connection has the more likely it will make problems (every plug/connector decreases the signal quality).

In the end the simplest way to solve your situation would be buying a cheap USB3.0 PCIEx card that has the suitable internal port for connecting your USB3.0 front panel.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use an internal pci-e card for this.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser and  the recommendation: I’m aware of the signal problem, which comes along with the high data rate, since I’m going to get my masters degree in electronic engineering this year.